# Create a list of maps from a data frame in R

Tags: r, json, list, data-manipulation

I have a data frame as follows:

[image]

I want to create a list of maps from the data frame. Below is the code I am using now:

```
list_tot <- list()
list_tot[[1]] <- list()
list_tot[[1]][['arId']] <- "AR-3739"
list_tot[[1]][['lrIds']] <- list()
list_tot[[1]][['lrIds']][[1]] <- "LR-125423"


list_tot[[2]] <- list()
list_tot[[2]][['arId']] <- "AR-3764"
list_tot[[2]][['lrIds']] <- list()
list_tot[[2]][['lrIds']][[1]] <- "LR-125424"

list_tot[[3]] <- list()
list_tot[[3]][['arId']] <- "AR-3678"
list_tot[[3]][['lrIds']] <- list()
list_tot[[3]][['lrIds']][[1]] <- "LR-125425"

jsonData <- toJSON(list_tot)
```

Below is the output:

```
"[{\"arId\":\"AR-3739\",\"lrIds\":[\"LR-125423\"]},{\"arId\":\"AR-3764\",\"lrIds\":[\"LR-125424\"]},{\"arId\":\"AR-3678\",\"lrIds\":[\"LR-125425\"]}]"
```

One "AR ID" can have several "LR ID", i.e., for each row, "LR ID" is unique, while "AR ID" can have duplicates. Could you please let me know whether there is a convenient way to do that if there are quite a few rows in the data frame. Thank you for your help.

Comment: "*One "AR ID" can have several "LR ID"*" -- your question would be much better if your example data demonstrated this issue, and your sample output showed how you want it to be handled.

Comment: Good suggestion. I have modified the sample data.

Comment: If you're interested in more solutions, would you also post your sample data in valid R syntax? It's annoying to import data from a picture of a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but it should work no matter how many rows you have in your data frame.
First, I've turned your excel table into a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  AR_ID = c("AR-3739", "AR-3764", "AR-3678"),
  LR_ID = c("LR-125423", "LR-125424", "LR-125425")
)
```

Then, to get your desired output:

```
library(dplyr)
get_sublist <- function(small_df) {
  list(arId = unique(small_df$AR_ID), lrIds = as.list(small_df$LR_ID))
}

unique_arids <- unique(df$AR_ID)
list_tot <- lapply(
  X = unique_arids,
  FUN = function(arid) {
    df %>%
      filter(AR_ID == arid) %>%
      get_sublist()
  }
)
jsonData <- toJSON(list_tot)
```

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you.